Conditional expectation on function of two variables
I have the following problem. I know the following things:
(1) $E(X | Z) = 0$
(2) $E(X|W) = 0$
I also know that W is independent of any variable (just a random draw).
I would like to show (or know whether it is possible) that:
(3) $E(X|W+Z) = 0$
Does this property follow from the above? And, if so, how?

Welcome to MSE, fefe! Do we know if $W$ is a continuous or a discrete variable?

Thank you! All three are continuous.

Are you sure this is the question that you want to ask? The equation $E(X|Z)=0$ does not make much sense, since $E(X|Z)$ is a random variable that is defined by $f(Z)$, where $f(z)=E(X|Z=z)$ for all $z$.

Considering $X$ and $W$ conditionally independent:
\begin{gather*}
E(X|W+Z)=\int E(X|W+Z,Z)dP_{Z/W+Z}=\int E(X|W,Z)dP_{Z/W+Z}=\\=\int E(X|Z)dP_{Z/W+Z}=\int 0dP_{Z/W+Z}=0
\end{gather*}
